# How do you include the borders in the query result when copying?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way I can include the borders on the query result window, after copying the data.  This would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Where are you pasting the copied data? If you are pasting in Excel, there is no need to include the borders. If it is in Word, you will need to format the table to have colored borders. If you are using a text editor like Notepad then there is no way to have borders.

Comment: In a email mostly.  But thanks anyways.  I have been pasting the data into Excel and creating the borders that way.

Comment: That is pretty much what you have to do. Copy/Paste copies the data, not the presentation, which will vary by application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but takes a few steps. Instead of just copying the result,

- right-click data grid (query result) and choose **Export ...**
- set

  - format: html
  - save as: single file
  - file: any you want, e.g. c:\temp\result.html
- finish

Navigate to destination folder (c:\temp in my example) and double-click the `result.html` file; it'll open in your default browser.

- `Ctrl+A` (to select all), `Ctrl+C` (to copy it)
- open e-mail client
- `Ctrl+V` (to paste clipboard contents)
- select the whole HTML table, set the border

That's all.

---

Unfortunately, SQL Developer lacks TOAD's functionality which lets you export to HTML, but directly into **clipboard** (SQL Developer won't let you do that), so you just have to paste the result into e-mail message. Quite simple, takes only 3 steps (right-click query results; export into HTML format, into the clipboard; paste).

Answer (score 0):

sqldeveloper has an option for export to CSV. In the result window select your columns rclick => Export Results => To clipboard as => CSV file.

```
 SELECT 1 AS SOME_NUMBER, 'abc' AS RANDOM_STRING, 'dfg' AS ANOTHER_STRING, SYSDATE AS SOME_DATE
   FROM dual

"SOME_NUMBER";"RANDOM_STRING";"ANOTHER_STRING";"SOME_DATE"
"1";"abc";"dfg";"30.12.2021 20:00:06"
```